# Open entity form in pop up window

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm-2015

i can open a new entity form using;

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("account");
```

I have tried using;

```
var features ="location = 1, status = 1,Popup,scrollbars=1, resizable=1, directories=1, toolbar=1, titlebar=1, width=600, height=600");

window.open("/main.aspx?etn=account&pagetype=entityrecord", "_blank", features, false);
```

But it does not work , Is there a better way of using `window.open` to open a new account form in a new window with a set size?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `windowOptions` of `openEntityForm` mentioned here? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the MSDN reference for openEntityForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_OpenEntityForm) it's supported since version 7.1

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(name, id, paremeters, windowOptions);
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That last parameter should be `{openInNewWindow: true}`

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks but how can i give it a set size?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not included in the features. I *hope* the new window is always big enough to see the form...